# how to read value from gridview (which is enclosed between update panel) into textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a 4 textboxs namely first_name,last_name,gender and department and one gridview. GridView contain edit and delete buttons. When the user click edit button the values from gridview will read into textbox and user will update it but when i use update panel to refresh only gridview not the whole page this will not work. Values can't read from gridview to textbox. I want only gridview view to refresh not the whole page. here is my code.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"            Inherits="Task2._Default" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <style type="text/css">
        .style2
        {
            width: 208px;
        }
        .style3
        {
            width: 81px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table style="width: 53%;">
        <tr>
            <td class="style3">
                First Name</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_FirstName" runat="server" Width="230px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style3">
                Last Name</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_LastName" runat="server" Width="230px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style3">
                Gender</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_Gender" runat="server" Width="230px" MaxLength="1"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style3">
                Department</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_Department" runat="server" Width="230px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" class="style3" colspan="1">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button_Save" runat="server" Text="Save" Width="107px" 
                        onclick="Button_Save_Click"/>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button_Update" runat="server" style="margin-left: 14px" 
                        Text="Update" Width="104px" onclick="Button_Update_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel_GridOne" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:GridView ID="GridOne" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        EmptyDataText="No Records Found" Width="419px" >
            <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="First_Name" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("First_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Last_Name" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Last_Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Gender" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Gender") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Department">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Department" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Department") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="Edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" OnClick="edit_button"/>
                                    <asp:Button ID="Delete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure? want to delete the record.');"  OnClick="delete_button"/>
                                    <asp:Label ID="EmployeeID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("EmployeeID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>           
                     </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hidEmployeeID" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
      </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have kept `UpdateMode="Conditional"`, that means you have to call `UpdatePanel_GridOne.Update()` method in cs file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also cover the textbox outside the gridview inside another update panel..

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2 runat="server" >
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_LastName" runat="server" Width="230px"></asp:TextBox>
 </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Jameem it worked but i think whole page is refreshing.
i want only gridview should be refreshed.